# How to externalize @SpringBootApplication configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to externalize the `@SpringBootApplication(exclude...)` option, to have a reusable class or annotation that I could throw in to exclude any database/hibernate initialization.

So, instead of writing:

```
@SpringBootApplication(
        exclude = {
                DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
                DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
                HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
public class MainApp {
}
```

I would like to create a annotation that I could apply to my `@SpringBootApplication` main class:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
        DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
@Configuration
public @interface ExcludeDataSources {
}
```

And then enable this feature by annotation:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ExcludeDataSources
public class MainApp {
}
```

Problem: the annotation approach does not work, and spring still tries to load a database. Why?

My final goal is to have multiple startup classes, where only one loads the database.

Comment: `@SpringBootApplication` contains `@EnableAutoConfiguration` without excludes, I am not sure which annotation will be chosen by Spring's meta annotation logic, but I would replace `@SpringBootApplication` with its annotations (except `@EnableAutoConfiguration` of course)

Comment: Why not set the configuration property [`spring.autoconfigure.exclude`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.auto-configuration.disabling-specific) to the list of auto-configuration classes to exclude? Set this configuration property inside a profile.

Comment: @ChinHuang because I don't run my application in different profiles (different jobs are triggered by program args).

Answer (score 2):

I could manage it by adding an additional `@EnableAutoConfiguration` that is only executed on a certain condition.
This way I can dynamically exclude the database config, while keeping a clean basis main `@SpringBootConfiguration` class.

```
public class DataSourceConfig {
    @Configuration
    @Conditional(MyCondition.class)
    @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
            DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
            DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
            HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
    static class ExcludeDataSource {
    }
}
```